# Instancia de Oracle bloqueada al realizar un CAST a VARCHAR2(32767)

Tags: cast, oracle-19c

Me encuentro trabajando con una versión 19c de Oracle, mi instancia esta configurada con MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED, por lo cual el valor máximo de VARCHAR2 es 32767 caracteres, al realizar un cast de un tipo de dato NUMBER obtengo el error:

```
Error de E/S: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
```

Reviso inmediatamente mi servicio de listener y el de mi instancia me aparece detenido, si realizo un cast de un campo de tipo cadena esto no sucede, mi CAST es el siguiente:

```
SELECT CAST(EDAD AS VARCHAR2(32767)) FROM PERSONA;
```

He solventado el error colocando un TO_CHAR, (SELECT CAST(TO_CHAR(EDAD) AS VARCHAR2(32767)) FROM PERSONA;) pero quisiera saber a que se debe que mi instancia termine siendo bloqueada, estuve haciendo pruebas con los valores de VARCHAR2 y ví que este error se presenta al colocar un valor igual o mayor que 4009, busque en internet el error pero lo que encontré fue relacionado a la instalación, no a mi caso, espero me puedan apoyar muchas gracias

Comment: Has revisado logs de la instancia?

Comment: No, no he entrado a ellos, en donde se encuentran?:(

Comment: He revisado el log de la instancia pero no me aparece ningún error referente a esto que me sucedio